# How to get the URL of a product within a Shopware command?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

I'm currently working on a Shopware project and I need to retrieve the URL of a product within a command class. The command is responsible for performing various actions on the products and requires the product URL to carry out certain operations.

How can I retrieve the URL of a specific product within a command class (https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-custom-commands)?

Here's an example of how my code looks like currently:

```php
...
$products = $this->productRepository->search($cri, $context)->getElements();

/** @var \Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductEntity $product */
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $formattedProduct = [
        'id' => $product->get('id'),
        'title' => $product->get('translated')['name'],
        'description' => $product->get('translated')['description'],
        'link' => '[HERE I NEED THE PRODUCT URL]'
    ];

    $formattedProducts[] = $formattedProduct;
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

When you fetch products add the `seoUrls` association to the criteria.

```php
$criteria->addAssociation('seoUrls');
```

Calling `getSeoUrls` on the product will return an instance of `SeoUrlCollection`.

```php
/** @var SeoUrlCollection $seoUrls */
$seoUrls = $product->getSeoUrls();
```

You can then go ahead and also filter that collection, e.g. to only include the canonical url of a certain sales channel.

```php
$url = $seoUrls->filter(function (SeoUrlEntity $seoUrl) use ($salesChannelId) {
    return $seoUrl->getIsCanonical() && $seoUrl->getSalesChannelId() === $salesChannelId;
})->first();
```

Comment: Thanks! How can i get the default sales channel?

Comment: There's no default sales channel. If you do have multiple, you will have to create a criteria to find the one you're looking for. If you have just one you can simply do `$salesChannelId = $container->get('sales_channel.repository')->searchIds($criteria, $context)->firstId();`